# Enviar campo de fecha vacio con PHP y HTML, MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, date, insert

tengo un problema y necesito de su ayuda.

Tengo un formulario con unos datos a llenar, el problema lo tengo en que un campo del tipo **"date"** que tengo como **no requerido** cuando se deja en **"vacio"** me inserta un dato "0000-00-00" y esto me genera aun problema ya que hago un calculo en base a esa fecha, entonces mi duda esta en que puedo hacer para que el campo llegue vacio, sin ningun dato.

En mi base de datos ya manejo este campo con **"Null"** cuando lo inserto de forma manual desde mi gestor el campo se queda vacio, desde mi formulario en **HTML** y enviado por **PHP** llega el valor **"0000-00-00"**

**HTML:**

```
Fecha de entrada a horno
<input type="date" name="FchEntrada" id="FchEntrada" class="form-control" />
```

**PHP:**

```
$nEmployee=trim($_POST['nEmployee']);
    $UbCamara=trim($_POST['UbCamara']);
    $MsdNparte=trim($_POST['MsdNparte']);
    $MsdQty=trim($_POST['MsdQty']);
    $FchExpiracion=trim($_POST['FchExpiracion']);
    $NivelMsd=trim($_POST['NivelMsd']);
    $Thickness=trim($_POST['Thickness']);
    $TmpHorno=trim($_POST['TmpHorno']);
    $FchSalida=trim($_POST['FchSalida']);
    $newFchSalida = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($FchSalida));
    $Dueno=trim($_POST['Dueno']);
    $comentarioR=trim($_POST['comentarioR']);
    $FchEntrada=trim($_POST['FchEntrada']);
    $turnos=trim($_POST['turnos']);
    $StatusPosition=trim($_POST['StatusPosition']);

$sql="INSERT into reparacion.reelsmsd (ubicacion,nparte,serial,qty,fchexp,fchent,nivel,Thickness,Thdays,FchSalida,Dueño,Comentarios,IdEmployee,Turno,StatusPosition)values ('$UbCamara','$MsdNparte','$SerialR','$MsdQty','$FchExpiracion','$FchEntrada','$NivelMsd','$Thickness','$TmpHorno','$newFchSalida','$Dueno','$comentarioR','$nEmployee','$turnos','$StatusPosition')";
mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

Trate de hacer un if, pero no me soluciono:

```
if ($FchEntrada=$_POST['FchEntrada'] == '0000-00-00') {
        $FchEntrada='';
}else{
        $FchEntrada=trim($_POST['FchEntrada']);
}
```

Comment: Esta de esa manera, pero no se por que me llega el dato 0000-00-00, lo explique arriba amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para insertar un `NULL` tienes que ponerlo sin comillas en el `$sql` y un `NOT NULL` tipo fecha si llevaría. Entonces podrías hacer algo así:

```
<?php
// ...
if ((!$FchEntrada) or ($FchEntrada == '0000-00-00')) { // Vacio o puros ceros
    $subq = "NULL";
} else {
    $subq = "'$FchEntrada'";
}

// Y luego
$sql = "INSERT into reparacion.reelsmsd (..., fchexp, fchent, nivel, ... )
VALUES (..., '$FchExpiracion', $subq, '$NivelMsd', ... )"; // $subq sin comillas.
```

Answer (score 0):

Para insertar un campo sin el formato que mencionas, puedes enviarle el valor NULL sin comillas.

```
if ($FchEntrada== '0000-00-00') {
        $FchEntrada=NULL;
}else{
        $FchEntrada=trim($_POST['FchEntrada']);
}
```

Debes tener en cuenta que NULL no es lo mismo que vacio.

Comment: Me sigue dando el problema :(

Comment: Estas haciendo el IF antes del insert cierto?

Comment: Asi es, trate de poner $FchEntrada == NULL; pero tampoco me resuelve